# Creating a toolbar in adobe flex 3

Tags: apache-flex

I am creating a Adobe Air Application. I have a menu and and I need to create a toolbar which has icons to represent some actions. Can you give me code or reference how to create toolbar and event handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a HBox and then add buttons inside (using an image as a style). Handle the click events of the buttons and that should work for toolbar icons. To handle wrapping of the toolbar, use the drag and drop event of the HBox over the stage or the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use  depending on which version of Flex you are using (Flex 3 or 4... mx:ApplicationControlBar is for Flex 3.5 compiler). An example would be... (<) means less than sign...

```
(<)mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true" id="toolbar">
    (<)mx:Image source="@Embed('imagepath/imagename.jpg')" click="clickfunction(event)" id="icon1" />
(<)/mx:ApplicatinoControlBar>
```

You would set your menu in ActionScript. Check out

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Menus_2.html.